# How to access an image from image view which is inside a cell of a collection view?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, cell

I have a collection view with cells filled with image & button (to add image to a gallery if related button is pressed)

(I need a didSelectItem delegate method for fullscreen action so I can't use it for add action)

I assigned the same tag to each cell and to each button within that cell so I can read a tag when button is pressed.

Now I need to access the image of related cell but what is the key to that image?

I am looking for something like:

```
@IBAction func addFromCell(_ sender: UIButton) {
imagesArray.append(myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: sender.tag).imageView.image)
}
```

But that does not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image in the cell is *view*. That's not what you want. Never treat view as data. What you want is the *data* for what image this is.

Ask yourself: How did the image get into the cell in the first place? It's because you put it there in your `cellForItemAt:` implementation. And how did your `cellForItemAt:` know what image to put into that cell? It looked in your *data model* based on the index path of the cell.

So when the button is pressed, all you need to know is the *index path* of the cell for that button, and now you just look up the image in your model. And that's easy to find out, because you know what cell this is, and so you know what index path it is occupying.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use closure to be able to access  to the button inside collection view cell.